# How can I use the arrow tool in Sketch App without navigating a menu every time?

Tags: sketch-app

I am designing a flow chart.  It requires lots and lots of use of the arrow tool, but there is no hotkey for it.  Therefore, every time I want to add an arrow, I have to navigate `Insert>Shape>Arrow` in the menu.

Surely, there is a better way.  How can I use this tool quickly, over and over again?  How can I use this tool without having to navigate the menu every time.

I tried creating a [custom shortcut through apples system preferences](https://medium.com/sketch-app-sources/sketch-tip-set-custom-keyboard-shortcuts-31652594522), but it did not work.  Perhaps there is a hotkey for re-do last command?

[image: Menu nav for arrow tool]

Comment: You could also select, copy and paste a existing arrow which will include all design changes.

Comment: That's what I ended up doing.  Not ideal, but fast enough.

Answer (score 3):

Sketch doesn't have any shortcut to do this but you can define a shortcut key.

1. Open **System Preferences**
2. Search **Keyboard Shortcuts**

[image: Keyboard Shortcuts Search]

3. Click on **App Shortcuts**

[image: App Shortcuts]

4. Hit **Plus(+)**
5. Select Sketch from the applications list
6. Type **"Insert->Shape->Arrow"** in Menu Title input.
7. Click on Keyboard Shortcut input and hit your favorite shortcut keys
8. Click on Add

[image: App Shortcuts]

10. Restart your Sketch and done:)

Comment: I linked this technique in my original question.  Did it work for you?  It did not work for me.

Comment: Yes, It works for me. Maybe your shortcut key is reserved by another plugin. Try to change your shortcut key. It doesn't appear in your insert menu located in toolbar, but you can see it in "Insert->Shape->Arrow" path.

Comment: I'd tried a bunch of them, but couldn't get it working.  :/

Comment: Have you tried with another application?